# dart - How to listen for Text-Change in Quill text Editor (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, events, flutter-layout, quill

I am only familiar with HTML/CSS/JS, and basics of dart/flutter

**Developer Level**: Beginner 
**Project type & language**: I am developing a notes app for myself, using **flutter**.

My aim is to save my note, as soon as I update the text... for which I need to use a dart Function to run on every 'text-change' event..

How do I use the `Text-Changes` event of Quill Editor to detect changes in the Content

THE EQUIVALENT OF THIS IN JAVASCRIPT IS GIVEN BELOW , BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO IT DART & FLUTTER.

```js
quill.on('text-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
  if (source == 'api') {
    console.log("An API call triggered this change.");
  } else if (source == 'user') {
    console.log("A user action triggered this change.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can listen to quill document changes stream and handle it accordingly.

```
_controller.document.changes.listen((event) {
  print(event.item1); //Delta
  print(event.item2); //Delta
  print(event.item3); //ChangeSource
});
```

Comment: This is a much helpful answer. Should be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

To listen for and detect changes in the Quill editor you can utilize the `QuillController` which provides a way to manage and interact with the Quill editor's state. Here's a breakdown of the process:

1. **Initialization**: First, create and initialize a `QuillController` instance. This controller is linked to the Quill editor and allows for the monitoring of text changes.

   ```dart
   late QuillController _quillController = QuillController.basic();
   ```
2. **Listening to Text Changes**: To detect changes in the editor's content, add a listener to the `QuillController` right after its initialization, typically inside the `initState` method of your widget. This listener will trigger a callback function whenever the text within the editor changes.

   ```dart
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     _quillController.addListener(_onEditorTextChanged);
   }
   ```
3. **Handling Text Changes**: The callback function `_onEditorTextChanged` is invoked whenever the editor's content changes. Within this function, you can access the current text of the editor and perform any necessary logic, such as parsing the text for specific patterns or updating the state of your widget based on the text content.

   ```dart
   void _onEditorTextChanged() {
     final text = _quillController.document.toPlainText();
     // Implement your logic here, such as searching for URLs or updating the UI.
   }
   ```
4. **Cleanup**: It's important to remove the listener when the widget is disposed to prevent memory leaks or unintended behavior. This is done in the `dispose` method.

   ```dart
   @override
   void dispose() {
     _quillController.removeListener(_onEditorTextChanged);
     super.dispose();
   }
   ```

Comment: hey @fedor may I know why you recommend deletion?

Answer (score -1):

I am also run into this issue. After some hours of research, I found a solution. You habe to add a listener to your `QuillController`, which will be called on each editor event, like pressed keys or toolbar actions.
Use the `initState()` method in your State class for adding a listener.

```
class _TextEditorState extends State<TextEditor> {

  final QuillController _controller = QuillController.basic();

  @override
  void initState() {
      _controller.addListener(() {
      print('Here I am, rock me like a hurricane!!!');
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build your Widget with QuillToolbar and QuillEditor here...
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to actually get the text value within the addListener function.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how it's done:

```dart
await for (final change in _quillEditorController.changes) {
  final oldDelta = change.toList()[0];
  final changeDelta = change.toList()[1];
  final changeSource = change.toList()[2];

  if (changeSource == ChangeSource.REMOTE) {
    console.log("An API call triggered this change.");
  } else if (changeSource == ChangeSource.LOCAL) {
    console.log("A user action triggered this change.");
  }
}
```

Note that flutter-quill's api doesn't exactly match quill.js. And since the documentation is lacking, your best hope in understanding what's available is by digging into the code-base using your editor (eg. using "go to definition").